# How to weak reference a function passed as a parameter

Tags: ios, swift

I have a strongly referenced model in my view controller that has a function `listenToQueue` which "listens" to my Firebase database for real time updates. Whenever an update occurs, it passes back an object to my view controller, which then calls a function. Here is my code:

```
eventModel.listenToQueue { [weak self] queuer in
    self?.queuerDidChange(queuer: queuer)
}
```

This works. However, originally my code looked like this:

```
eventModel.listenToQueue(updateHandler: queuerDidChange)
```

This caused a retain cycle between the model and the view controller. However, that code looks cleaner, so I'm wondering if there's a way to pass the `queuerDidChange` function via a weak reference to self? I tried this already, but the retain cycle is still there:

```
weak var weakSelf = self
eventModel.listenToQueue(updateHandler: weakSelf?.queuerDidChange)
```

Is it possible to do what I want, or shall I just stick to the code I've got?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed this in one of my apps. I like the look of passing in the method itself, but I also had to use the weak reference technique you mentioned.

This makes sense, I think, because method implementations are held on the class itself, and `self` is bound to that implementation when classes are instantiated. Therefore a method will always have a strong reference to `self`.

And in Swift, function parameters are strongly referenced. I don’t think there’s a way to pass any parameter using a weak reference.

Answer (score 15):

```
weak var weakSelf = self
eventModel.listenToQueue(updateHandler: weakSelf?.queuerDidChange)
```

Above code is the same code as:

```
eventModel.listenToQueue(updateHandler: queuerDidChange)
```

Because you declare `weakSelf` and use it immediately. `weakSelf?.queuerDidChange` has no relation to `weakSelf`, instead it already contains reference to `self` itself. I assume `queuerDidChange` member function. So the only way to avoid retain cycle is what you call the dirty way.

```
eventModel.listenToQueue { [weak self] queuer in
    self?.queuerDidChange(queuer: queuer)
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to enforce the [weak self] in the closure definition inside the function signature? E.g. : listenToQueue(_ closure:(weak EventModel)->Void)

Comment: @A.L.Strine There isn't and I believe won't be

Answer (score 0):

You can box or move the ugliness to the method if you want:

```swift
eventModel.listenToQueue(updateHandler: queuerDidChange)

...

func queuerDidChange(queuer: QueuerType) -> {} {
     { [weak self] in
         // do something
     }
}
```

I don't know your types so this is just an example.
In this version, you're shifting the ugliness to the class method which returns a new closure every time and captures `self` weakly. This is semantically identical to using the closure inline.

Personally, I find this explicit syntax confusing, especially with all the brackets but wanted to offer another option.